# wrapping a function in a pollSever function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an already defined function and now want to add a `pollServer` function to it so that this functions runs over and over. I keep getting errors when I try to wrap the existing function in another. Is there a better way to do this?

```
function callD(id) {
  jQuery('document').ready(function pollServer(){
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      var ab = document.getElementById('a')
      console.log(ab);
      var bod = document.getElementById(+id)

      if (ab == null) {
        bod.style.background='green'
      } else {
        bod.style.background='blue'
      }  
    }, 1200);  
  })
}
callD();
pollServer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, jQuery can make things pretty gnarly with all the nested callbacks. To make the code cleaner and easier to understand, I like to split my functions up and define them all at the top-most level of the script, then *compose* them together like so:

```js
/**
 * this function will check for the existing elements
 * and update styles
 */
function setBodyStyle(id) {
  var ab = document.getElementById('a');
  console.log(ab);
  var bod = document.getElementById(+id);

  if (ab == null) {
    bod.style.background='green';
  } else {
    bod.style.background='blue';
  }  
}

/**
 * this function will create a timeout or interval
 * which will in turn run setBodyStyle()
 */
function pollServer() {

  // I think you want setInterval here if you're polling?
  // setInterval will run _every_ 1200ms,
  // setTimeout only runs once after 1200ms
  window.setInterval(function() {

    // not sure where you're getting id from,
    // but you'll want to pass it here
    setBodyStyle();
  }, 1200);
}

// when the document is ready, run pollServer()
jQuery(document).ready(pollServer);
```

Having small functions that do one thing is just best-practice for the reasons I mentioned above. This will help your script be more understandable, which will help you find bugs.

For example, two things I don't understand about your code above:

1. where does the `id` variable come from? I don't see you passing it to your function from anywhere
2. how does your script poll the server? I don't see the code for that anywhere either.

Comment: Thanks so much there are actually 3 other calls callA-callC that are not shown since they didnt matter to my question and would have show a lot of code that wasnt needed. I actually need the window.setTimeout in there to delay this function from running and I need the pollServer.

Comment: np! Well I'm not sure how else to answer this -- the code that you posted won't work as is, but if there's more code missing that also doesn't work as you expect, I can't really understand or solve the problem unless you share it or a simplified version of it. If you're looking for an answer to why the code you posted doesn't work, [Zac Anger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743654/14825873) seems right!

Answer (score 1):

`pollServer` isn't defined where you're calling it. Also `id` isn't being passed to `callD`, and you also have a `+id` which doesn't make sense in a `document.getElementByid`, since if there's any non-number in the ID, that would be `NaN`. You're also not polling a server, you're setting a timeout once and doing some work that doesn't involve a server. You would want `setInterval` for regular polling, or to call the function again on some condition like a failure.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var intervalId;

  function callD(id) {
    function pollServer() {
      intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        var ab = document.getElementById('a')
        console.log(ab);
        var bod = document.getElementById(id)

        if (ab == null) {
          bod.style.background='green'
        } else {
          bod.style.background='blue'
        }  
      }, 1200);  
    }

    pollServer();
  }

  callD('some-id');
  // on some condtion eventually:
  clearInterval(intervalId);
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt post the rest of the other functions since they were not relevant which is why you dont see where ID is coming from. I actually need the `window.setTimeout` in there to delay this function from running and I need the pollServer

Answer (score 0):

Seemed you mean run the function `pollServer` every 1.2 sec. If so, you'd need to do two things

- Use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`
- Delete the last line for the `pollServer` function, because it is not accessible from outside the `ready` function block.